# Update SQL table with button click

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to website building and was wondering if anyone would be able to assist me with an issue I am having. I am creating a standard shopping website with a database for the products for an assignment and trying to reduce the  quantity column by 1 every time a button is clicked. What I have attempted to do is create a javascript function which updates the table when clicked, however nothing happens at the moment. Due to my novice knowledge ability, I do not know if this is the right method for updating a mysql table and any assistance on the correct method would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

      $sql = "SELECT id, name, description, price , quantity FROM products;";                //access table named products

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while(list($id, $name, $description, $price, $quantity) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { // while loop to output columns in table

        echo "<tr>";// table

            echo "<td>$name</td>";// echo name column
            echo "<td>$description</td>";// echo description column
            echo "<td>$price</td>";// echo price column
                            echo "<td>$quantity</td>";//echo quantity column
            echo "<td><a href=\"shoppingcart.php?action=add&id=$id\">Add     To Cart</a></td>";// Hyperlink to shopping cart

        echo "</tr>";


    }



    if ($quantity <= 9 ) // if statement for quantity
            {
                $msg = "Stock is low";
                mail("*******@hotmail.com","My subject",$msg);
            }
?>
 </table>
 <script>
  function myfunction() // javascript function 
  {
  <?php
   mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET quantity - 1 9 WHERE id = '1'");// update quantity
   mysqli_close($con);

?>
 }
</script>

<a href="shoppingcart.php">View Cart</a> // view cart hyperlink
<button onclick="myfunction()">Click</button> // click button to call my function

</body>
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can use PHP on the fly?  Would probably need AJAX or something like that?

Comment: You're mixing two types of MySQL APIs, so that's a "no go" right there.

Comment: yeah, building a shopping cart as one of your first websites is probably the better course of action :p what about following simple tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:** You can't use php functions (`mysqli` — php function) in JavaScript code.

**Explanation:** Learn how client and server interact with each other. Client sends request to the server. Server handles this request with php, sends you some html code (which is generated by php) and java script code (same as html). PHP did his work at this point. Now JavaScript code starts his work. JavaScript works in users browser, he can't use functions and objects of php (note, that there are no php at this step). In JavaScript you can do some ajax request to server, which you will handle with php again and send some html/json data to browser again. When all this actions done, php end's and javascript starts. Etc etc etc.

So...

**Solution:** You can make ajax request on button click:

```
var data = // put some data here
$("#buttonID").on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourPhpScriptWhereYouWillExecuteYourQuery.php";
        data: data
    });
}
```

Look at `url` field. When you click button, ajax-request to this url will be sent. Also, data from field `data` will be sent with this request.

Answer (score 0):

I see where your thought process is coming from, and I like it! But it's incorrect. See, you can't embed PHP in javascript like this

```
 function myfunction( // javascript function 
  {
  <?php
   mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET quantity - 1 9 WHERE id = '1'");// update quantity
   mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

because javascript is client-side and PHP is server-side, which means that, essentially, the two don't see each other, so you actually have an empty function. 
However, if you want to use javascript to do this, you can use AJAX. Now "vanilla" javascript ajax calls aren't that hard to use, but jquery is much easier! You could do something like this

```
function ajaxFunction(){
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "doStuff.php",
          data: {key: value}, //data to send as key-value pairs
          context: this,
          success: function(data){
            //do stuff when done running
          }
        });
}
```

and that should do the trick!

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23299060/2898694) didn't helped you, @user3573636?